# How to escape sprintf specifier in a portion of the format string that may has %

Tags: php, escaping, printf

### The code:

```
<?php
$tableName = 'users';
$position = 1;
$paths = ['index'];     
    $sqlFormat = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE (";
    for ($i =0; $i < count($paths); $i++){
      if ($i == (count($paths)-1)){
        $sqlFormat .= "path LIKE '%%$paths[$i]%%') ";       
      }
      else{
        $sqlFormat .= "path LIKE '%%$paths[$i]%%' OR ";     
      }   
    }
    $sqlFormat .= "AND (position = $position) AND published = 'Y' ";
    $sqlFormat .= "ORDER BY weight ASC";
    $sql = sprintf($sqlFormat, $tableName);
    echo $sql;
```

### Symptoms:

When the `$paths` array contain ordinary string it works fine. However, if we set paths to `$paths = ['index%'];` it generates `PHP Warning:  sprintf(): Too few arguments...`. In other words, if `$paths` contains values has the `%` sign. In this situation I could not able to use `%%` to escape, like occurred in the like clause of the SQL above `...LIKE '%%$paths[$i]%%...`because `$paths` may contain `%` optionally.

I could not able to find a way that let optional escaping of `%` if it exists. All similar questions talk about escaping of fixed values

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that I have found by using `str_replace()` for the elements of the array `paths` to replace one `%` by two `%%` to solve the issue:

```
$sqlFormat .= "path LIKE '%%".str_replace('%','%%',$paths[$i])."%%') ";
```

So if the the element contains any single `%` it would be escaped for the `sprintf` by doubling it.